# Upgrading Cygwin x86 to x64 (32-bit vs 64-bit Cygwin)

Tags: cygwin

I'm a long-time user of Cygwin. I'm running Win7/x64, but my Cygwin installation is 32-bit. At the time I installed it, 64-bit version was considered experimental. Now the Cygwin website lists 32-bit and 64-bit versions on their website without any special mentions or recommendations on which one to use.

As a programmer, my experience is: unless specifically designed for capabilities of 64-bit CPUs, very few applications can get any gains by being recompiled for a 64-bit CPU. They might use more memory, though, since each memory pointer now uses 8 bytes rather than 4.

So, my question is: is there any benefit to choose 64-bit Cygwin over 32-bit ones? Should I upgrade my 32-bit installation sooner or later?

Performance/memory benchmark results for common usage patterns (e.g. running common UNIX commands, particular shell scripts etc.) would be very welcome.

If you've upgraded your 32-bit Cygwin to 64-bit, please tell your story - was the upgrade worth it?

EDIT: I've been using 64-bit Cygwin for a while now, and haven't really noticed any differences - good or bad - from the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 9):

After running 32-bit Cygwin at work for a number of years, I recently upgraded to 64-bit. It was quite painless as you can run the two installations side-by-side.  For me, there was no noticeable difference in performance though I did not run any benchmarks.  The biggest gain for me in upgrading was starting with a new fresh install without any of the cruft that built up over the last few years.

The one disadvantage that I had when running 32-bit Cygwin was that the [WoW64 subsystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) filesystem redirector silently redirects 32-bit applications. This has the result that running `ls /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/` in 32-bit Cygwin doesn’t actually display the contents of `%WINDIR%\System32`, but instead `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64`. Attempts to access files in the `%WINDIR%\System32` directory, e.g., `ls /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/nbtstat.exe` fail with the error message:

```
ls: cannot access /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/nbtstat.exe: No such file or directory
```

This means that Windows commands installed in `%WINDIR%\System32` such as `nbtstat` and `dnscmd` aren’t available without modifying the `PATH`.  The work-around for accessing 64-bit Windows files was that the `%SystemRoot%\sysnative` pseudo-directory had to be used, e.g., to run the `nbtstat` command, use `/cygdrive/c/Windows/Sysnative/nbtstat`.

### 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows

[WoW64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) (Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit) is a subsystem capable of running 32-bit applications. It is included on all 64-bit versions of Windows and creates a 32-bit environment to run unmodified 32-bit applications on a 64-bit system using DLLs to provide the necessary interfaces.

> Windows uses the `%SystemRoot%\system32` directory for its 64-bit library and executable files. This is done for backward compatibility reasons, as many legacy applications are hardcoded to use that path.  When executing 32-bit applications, WoW64 transparently redirects 32-bit DLLs to `SystemRoot%\SysWoW64`, which contains 32-bit libraries and executables.
>
> 32-bit applications are generally not aware that they are running on a 64-bit operating system. 32-bit applications can access `%SystemRoot%\System32` through the pseudo directory `%SystemRoot%\sysnative`.

For 64-bit applications (such as Windows Command Prompt, cmd.exe) there’s no filesystem redirection:

See also: [File System Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Now that I've answered this question, it occurs to me that it would be more appropriate for Super User.

Comment: In addition fork failure on 64bit are extremely rare compared to 32bit

Comment: @matzeri Now that you mention it, I haven't had a fork failure since I upgraded. I used to get them when using `git` to pull from a repository with a lot of update data. Good point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Don't use any of the tools you mentioned so that point is not important to me. No fork failures sounds good, although I haven't seen any fork failures ever. Is there a particular error message when they occur?
So, you haven't noticed any performance/memory usage issues? I've read a question where a `grep` on Cygwin64 ran significantly longer and used tons of memory, that was probably a bug that is now fixed, I would guess.

Comment: I did a performance benchmark in my answer with a find piped to grep then redirected to a file, and the performance gain is well worth it for CPU intensive tasks.

Answer (score 3):

**I ran one I/O heavy benchmark, but even for this the noticeable performance gain is well worth it.**

On a cygwin bash shell on Windows 7, I ran a find of many patterns piped to grep and then redirected to a file on the same hard drive in 32 and 64 bit:

**32 bit**

real    1m58.57s    **68% more time**
user    0m11.95s   **41% more time**
sys     0m40.83s    **23% more time**

**64 bit**

real    1m10.36s
user    0m8.50s
sys     0m33.05s